no reachable servers. MongoDB error with go using gopkg.in/mgo.v2
I am trying to establish connection with mongoDB using the below code
func getSession() \*mgo.Session {

    // Connect to MongoDB on the default port
    s, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to connect to MongoDB: ", err)
    }
    
    return s

}

MongoDb is running on port 27017. I am using "gopkg.in/mgo.v2". Please help
I have verified the connection for mongoDB and its running on the default port.

Use the official mongodb driver.

Seems to be a bug in your code or code you're calling. Step through this with a debugger to find out what's going on. With the little code, it's impossible to tell, provide a [mcve] instead. Also, how did you set up the DB and how do you verify it works?

I figured out the issue and its because of the old packages I was using. I have updated my code with the new packages and it works fine now. Thanks for your response. Really appreciate it!!

Then feel free to answer your own question (and be nice to reference @BurakSerdar, since his comment was correct).
